Are there any libraries for generating synthetic anomalies in timeseries data in python?
I'm working on anomaly detection in timeseries data, and need to add synthetic anomalies to existing timeseries data (in order to test anomaly detection algorithms).
I can do this by running a function to modify a timeseries at random points, which works, but I'm wondering if there are any libraries in the python ecosystem which do this.
Ideally, I'd want to pass an array (or pandas series) to a function and have another returned with anomalies inserted by various means, and of various kinds. For example I might want random noise added, or the series set to zero for an interval, or the mean of the series increased, or random outliers added, etc.
I have found https://github.com/KIT-IAI/GeneratingSyntheticEnergyPowerAnomalies , and there are lots of libraries for anomaly detection, but I can't find anything specific for adding anomalies.
The point of using a library is that there are probably kinds of anomalies I haven't considered, or don't know I need yet, or might otherwise be useful.

https://github.com/KDD-OpenSource/agots might be useful
